# Volumetric lighting doesn't work

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I am using Blender 2.8 with Eevee  and there is a light source behind a window, if I hide the window the light works but not with the window. I tried to change the material setting but without success. How can I solve this?
[image: With windows] 
[image: when I hide windows]

EDIT: today I opened the file and it works, I didn't change anything from the last time, so strange...

Comment: Can you post a picture of the material settings on the window? For example, if the blend mode is still "Opaque", no light will show through.

Comment: I tried every material settings and none worked, today when I open the file it worked in every mode, even in opaque. It's strange, I didn't change anything